# The table cell does not update when we update word to word for Arabic and some languages when the cell reached over the table height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

In my case there is chat screen and i am getting response word to word on socket and want to update  word to word response on single chat cell on receiving side, but its working fine with engalish and some langugage,but its stuck with Arabic and some type of langugages, i am confuse why its happening, I try to update table cell in main thread with dispatch que but still getiing same issue.

```
let updatedChat = try? ChatSQLiteSqlQuery.shareInstance.getchatAccordingToSessions(sessionUUID: sessionUUID)
            if updatedChat.count > 0 {
                var indexPathsToUpdate: [IndexPath] = []
                var row = 0
                
                for (index, chat) in updatedChat.enumerated() {
                    if chat.messageId == messageId {
                        row = index
                        break
                    }
                }
                
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
                indexPathsToUpdate.append(indexPath)
                
                UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                    self.tablView_Chat.performBatchUpdates {
                        self.arrchat = updatedChat
                        self.tablView_Chat.beginUpdates()
                        self.tablView_Chat.reloadRows(at: indexPathsToUpdate, with: .none)
                        self.tablView_Chat.endUpdates()
                        
                    } completion: { _ in
                        self.tablView_Chat.scrollToBottom(isAnimated: false)
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tried layout update and also decode Unicode in a specific language and trying to update it, and also try to table view will display delegate to improve performance but did not get successes result

```
self.tablView_Chat.layoutIfNeeded()
self.tablView_Chat.setNeedsLayout()
self.tablView_Chat.layoutSubviews()
```

Actually, it is happening that, every second I am updating a lot of characters in the table cell, then the UI gets stuck.

Comment: Unrelated but `begin-/endUpdates` and also `performBatchUpdates`  has no effect at all when calling `reloadRows`.